# Enable graphic designer to use JSF GUI components?

Tags: jsf, user-interface, graphic

Is there a software that would enable graphic designer to use JSF GUI components in the initial web page design, before it gets into programmer's hands? Currently, graphic designer creates normal htmls using standard html components, then JSF programmer needs to replace all usual html tags with JSF tags. 
Does any web design-programming tool suport JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Oracle's JDeveloper. It's the only IDE that allows you to drag and drop JSF controls. The IDE is available only for Windows and Linux machines. Here is the link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html